# DataGridView column to display object's ToString()

Tags: c#, datagridview, tostring

I have a DataGridView which is bound to a BindingSource (which is built off a list of objects). I have used the BindingSource as the DataSource for the DataGridView and I would like to display the `ToString()` method of the objects in one column of the DataGridview.

How can i do this?

code:

```
List<DynstSection> sectionlist = new blockloader.Blockloader(app).getDynStDb();
sectionlist.Sort();

bs_sections.DataSource = sectionlist;

listBox1.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
listBox1.DataSource = bs_sections;
DataGridViewColumn col = new DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn();
col.DataPropertyName = "Checked";
col.HeaderText = "Checked";
col.Name = "Checked";
col.Width = 20;
listBox1.Columns.Add(col);
DataGridViewColumn col2 = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
col2.ReadOnly = true;
col2.DataPropertyName = HERE I WOULD LIKE TO HAVE TOSTRING()  
col2.HeaderText = "Name";
col2.Name = "Name";
col2.AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.Fill;
listBox1.Columns.Add(col2);
```

Comment: Do nothing - you will automatically get the `ToString()` if you bind to the object itself without specifying a property.

Comment: add the rows using a loop instead of binding them. or expose a property of the class (that you are binding) that returns the tostring method of that class

Comment: have used @EhsanUllah's solution. Looks like a workaround but it seems to work. If no one knows a way to display calculated (method) items in a datagridview i will mark this as answer if you post it.

Comment: @benst i have posted it as answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add the rows using a loop instead of binding them. or expose a property of the class (that you are binding) that returns the tostring method of that class

Comment: exposing the property is enough. Can still bind using a bindingsource. Will mark this as answer because @Ehsan posted it in the comments befor user713248 did.

Answer (score 2):

One solution is to create a property and in the getter of that property, to call the ToString() method, as follows:

```
public MyToStringProperty {get{return this.ToString();}}
```

Don't forget to raise notification when the ToString() method's return value changes.